# SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

We have two build agents (Ubuntu 12.04), both have NodeJS 5 and Gulp 3.9 installed:

```
$ nodejs -v
v5.11.1

$ npm list | grep gulp
├─┬ gulp@3.9.1
```

But during `gulp build` - one agent works successfully, and other - return an error:

```
$ gulp build
/var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/Worker/gulpfile.js:3
let requireDir = require('require-dir');
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp:19:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: I'm guessing that your code needs to be in strict mode in order to use some ES6 syntax you are using.  One possibility would be to upgrade to node 6.x.

Comment: let is ES6, If you run ES5 in strict mode I believe you get this error

Comment: try with using 'use strict';
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: 'use strict' does not work if you are using v0.12.7 or any v.0 +, so I have upgraded to the latest and stable version by typing 'n latest'. It is recommended to run 'npm rebuild' and all should be fine.